# Argument 1 passed to Application\Controller\IndexController::__construct() must be an instance of Application\Model\EmployeeTable, none given

Tags: zend-framework2

I stuck With this Issue in Zd2 and knocking my head from last 2 days but not come up with any solution. Will be very Appreciable If anyone Can help me out with the below given error.
Argument 1 passed to Application\Controller\IndexController::__construct() must be an instance of Application\Model\EmployeeTable, none given

Here is my Application Module Config file module.config.php

> namespace Application;
>
> use Zend\Router\Http\Literal; use Zend\Router\Http\Segment; use
>   Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
>
> return [
>           [
>               'controllers' => [
>                   'invokables' => [
>                       'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
>                   ],
>                   'factories' => [
>                       'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Factory\IndexControllerFactory'
>                   ],
>               ]
>
> ```
>     ],
>     'router' => [
>     'routes' => [
>         'home' => [
>             'type' => Literal::class,
>             'options' => [
>                 'route'    => '/',
>                 'defaults' => [
>                     'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
>                     'action'     => 'index',
>                 ],
>             ],
>         ],
>         'application' => [
>             'type'    => Segment::class,
>             'options' => [
>                 'route'    => '/application[/:action]',
>                 'defaults' => [
>                     'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
>                     'action'     => 'index',
>                 ],
>             ],
>         ],
>     ],
> ],
> 'view_manager' => [
>     'display_not_found_reason' => true,
>     'display_exceptions'       => true,
>     'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
>     'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
>     'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
>     'template_map' => [
>         'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
>         'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
>         'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
>         'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
>     ],
>     'template_path_stack' => [
>         __DIR__ . '/../view',
>     ],
> ], ];
> ```

Application Index Controller

> table = $table;
>       }
>       public function indexAction() {
>           $view = new ViewModel([
>               'data' => $this->table->fetchAll(),
>           ]);
>           return $view;
>       } }

Module.php file

> class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface {
>       const VERSION = '3.0.3-dev';
>
> ```
> public function getConfig()
> {
>     return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
> }
> public function getServiceConfig() {
>     return  [
>         'factories' => [
>             Model\EmployeeTable::class => function ($container) {
>                 $tableGateway = $container>get(Model\EmployeeTableGateway::class);
>                 $table = new Model\EmployeeTable($tableGateway);
>                 return $table;
>             },
>             Model\EmployeeTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
>                 $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
>                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
>                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Employee());
>                 return new TableGateway('employee', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
>             },
>         ],
>     ];
> }
> public function getControllerConfig() {
>     return  [
>         'factories' => [
>             Controller\IndexController::class => function($container) {
>                 return new Controller\IndexController(
>                     $container->get(EmployeeTable::class)
>                 );
>             },
>         ],
>     ];
> } }
> ```

Model Employee

> class Employee {
>       public $id;
>       public $emp_name;
>       public $emp_job;
>       public function exchangeArray($data) {
>           $this->id = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
>           $this->emp_name = (!empty($data['emp_name'])) ? $data['emp_name'] : null;
>           $this->emp_job = (!empty($data['emp_job'])) ? $data['emp_job'] : null;
>       } }

Model EmployeeTable

> use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
>   use  Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;
>
> class EmployeeTable {
>       protected $tableGateway;
>       public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway) { $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway; }
>       public function fetchAll() {
>           $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
>           return $resultSet;
>       } }

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

I the above Module.php, either write on top of the class

```
 use Model\EmployeeTable;
```

Or, set an aliases to `"Model\EmployeeTable::class"`

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
        return  [
            'factories' => [
                Model\EmployeeTable::class => function ($container) {
                    $tableGateway = $container>get(Model\EmployeeTableGateway::class);
                    $table = new Model\EmployeeTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                Model\EmployeeTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                    $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Employee());
                    return new TableGateway('employee', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ],
            'aliases' => array(
                EmployeeTable::class => Model\EmployeeTable::class
            )
        ];
    }
```